# What is the difference between pre($ENV{'QUERY_STRING}) and ($cgi->param())?

Tags: perl, cgi, environment-variables, parameters

for a perl cgi script, what is the difference (technically) between these two?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use CGI; 
$cgi = new CGI; 
print $cgi->header(),
$cgi->start_html(),
$cgi->pre($cgi->param()), 
$cgi->end_html();
```

and

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use CGI; 
$cgi = new CGI; 
print $cgi->header(),
$cgi->start_html(), 
$cgi->pre($ENV{'QUERY_STRING'}), 
$cgi->end_html();
```

Comment: Please stop using the dirty old CGI.pm. Use instead a modern and clean web engine such as [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) or [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume an HTTP request like this:

```
GET my.cgi?foo=bar&baz=buz
```

When run under a webserver with a conventional CGI interface, the environment variable QUERY_STRING will be `foo=bar&baz=buz`.  The environment variable will not be URL-unescaped.  Printing it with `$cgi->pre(...)` will simply enclose the env var with `<pre></pre>` tags (or a single `<pre />` tag if the value is or is coerced to an empty string.

`$cgi->param()`, on the other hand, and assuming a list context with no arguments, will return a *list* of *URL-unescaped* CGI parameter names, in this case `foo` and `bar`.

(Note that `$cgi->pre(...)` does *not* HTML-escape its argument, so `$ENV{QUERY_STRING}` might just jeopardize your cgi with a little cross-site scripting injection.)

Answer (score 1):

The `param` method on the CGI object returns a list of all query parameters, including GET and POST parameters. Unless you pass in an argument, in which case it looks for a parameter with that name and returns the value.

The `QUERY_STRING` environment variable contains the unparsed query string.

This would have been pretty obvious if you had tried the code in question.

[Here](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/CGI.pm-3.48/lib/CGI.pm#FETCHING_THE_NAMES_OF_ALL_THE_PARAMETERS_PASSED_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT:) is the documentation for `param`.

Answer (score -1):

Per the source of [CGI.pm](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/LDS/CGI.pm-3.48/lib/CGI.pm)

```
#### Method: param
# Returns the value(s)of a named parameter.
# If invoked in a list context, returns the
# entire list.  Otherwise returns the first
# member of the list.
# If name is not provided, return a list of all
# the known parameters names available.
# If more than one argument is provided, the
# second and subsequent arguments are used to
# set the value of the parameter.
```

`QUERY_STRING` is set by the web server it is simply the query string from the uri: [you can read more about it here](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/env_var.htm)